# Implementing an Error-Class for an invalid input field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Firstly my HTML Code:

```
<form name="Form" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" ng-model="item.name" required="" aria-describedby="" />
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">(error)</span>
      <br />
      <div class="has-error has-feedback" ng-show="Form.$submitted || Form.Name.$touched">
         <span ng-show="Form.Name.$error.required">Name is invalid.</span>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I want to show div class "has-error has-feedback" and the glyphicon only, when the name is invalid. How can I develop this?

Comment: ng-show and ng-class will probably be useful. both of them take conditional. the condition is that name input is dirty and invalid.

Comment: I've added a `ng-class="Form.Isin.$error.required ? 'has-error' : 'has-success'`, but when the page is loaded, the inputfield is immediately red. The inputfield should be red, when I'm going to the next inputfield. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display according to it being invalid, you need to do this:

```
<div class="has-error has-feedback" ng-show="Form.Name.$invalid">
     <span ng-show="Form.Name.$error.required">Name is invalid.</span>
</div>
```

Same for the glyphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="Form.Name.$invalid"></span>
```